# Can an exponent be stored as a floating point number?

Tags: binary, floating-point

I would like to know if a binary exponent can be stored in floating point form. Here is a example of what I mean:

In a system floating point numbers use a `10-bit two's complement mantissa` and a `6-bit floating point exponent`

Convert `0101001000 000100` into denary:

Well if I assume that the exponent is in normal binary, the exponent equals 4

So the decimal point in the mantissa goes here initially:

```
0.101001000
```

Then we move the decimal point 4 places to the right, yielding

```
01010.01
```

Which equals `10.25` in denary.

This answer will be wildly different if the exponent can be stored as with a decimal. I am asking if the exponent can be stored in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if a binary exponent can be stored in floating point form

Yes.
To form the *denary* from a *string*, use `strtol()`.

To covert the *denary* into a floating-point, extract the bits  into its "mantissa" and exponent.   Form the FP value with `ldexp()`.

```
double ldexp(double x, int exp);
```

> The `ldexp` functions multiply a floating-point number by an integral power of 2.
>   c11dr §7.12.6.7 2

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define denary_MANIISSA_EXPO 9
#define denary_MANIISSA_MASK 0xFFC0u
#define denary_EXPO_SCALE 64

double denary_to_double(denary d) {
  int expo = d & (denary_EXPO_SCALE - 1);
  int mantissa = (d - expo) / denary_EXPO_SCALE;
  return ldexp(mantissa, expo - denary_MANIISSA_EXPO);
}

void denary_test(const char *s) {
  denary d = (denary) strtol(s, NULL, 2);
  printf("0x%04X -->", d & 0xFFFF);
  printf(" %+.9f\n", denary_to_double(d));
}
int main(void) {
  denary_test("0101001000" "000100");
  denary_test("0000000000" "000000"); // zero
  denary_test("0000000001" "000000"); // denary_POS_MIN
  denary_test("1111111111" "000000"); // denary_NEG_MIN
  denary_test("0111111111" "111111"); // denary_POS_MAX
  denary_test("1000000000" "111111"); // denary_NEG_MAX
}
```

Output

```
0x5204 --> +10.250000000
0x0000 --> +0.000000000
0x0040 --> +0.001953125
0xFFC0 --> -0.001953125
0x7FFF --> +9205357638345293824.000000000
0x803F --> -9223372036854775808.000000000
```